# Функция шаблон в классе

Tags: c++, ооп, функции

Есть класс автобус. Есть после destination (маршрут который проходит) petrol (количество бензина потраченного). Необходимо написать шаблон функции для подсчета среднего значения маршрута и среднего значения бензина который был потрачен. Я не могу понять задачу. Реально ли написать такую функцию?

```
class Bus {
           int destination;
           double petrol;
    };
```

Comment: В заголовке сказано "шаблон в классе". Почему именно "шаблон"? И что значит "в классе"?

Comment: Реально. Такой шаблон по идее будет устранять дублирование кода принимая в качестве параметра тип `int` или `double`.